# SQL Year over year growth percentage from data same query

Tags: sql, ms-access

How do I calculate the percentage difference from 2 different columns, calculated in that same query? Is it even possible?

This is what I have right now:

```
SELECT 
      Year(OrderDate) AS [Year], 
      Count(OrderID) AS TotalOrders, 
      Sum(Invoice.TotalPrice) AS TotalRevenue
FROM 
    Invoice 
INNER JOIN Order
        ON Invoice.InvoiceID = Order.InvoiceID
GROUP BY Year(OrderDate);
```

Which produces this table

[image]

Now I'd like to add one more column with the YoY growth, so even when 2016 comes around, the growth should be there..

EDIT:
I should clarify that I'd like to have for example next to

```
2015,5,246.28 -> 346,15942029% ((R2015-R2014) / 2014 * 100)
```

Comment: MySQL and MS Access are two very different products. Are you sure you're using both here?

Comment: Please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Not sure what difference between two columns mean. Do you mean between two rows? Show us Sample data and your desire result

Comment: Im using MS Access, Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you save your existing query as *qryBase*, you can use it as the data source for another query to get what you want:

```sql
SELECT
    q1.Year,
    q1.TotalOrders,
    q1.TotalRevenue,
    IIf
        (
            q0.TotalRevenue Is Null,
            Null,
            ((q1.TotalRevenue - q0.TotalRevenue) / q0.TotalRevenue) * 100
        ) AS YoY_growth
FROM
    qryBase AS q1
    LEFT JOIN qryBase AS q0
    ON q1.Year = (q0.Year + 1);
```

Access may complain it *"can't represent the join expression q1.Year = (q0.Year + 1) in Design View"*, but you can still edit the query in SQL View and it will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked! Do you know a way to limit the decimals of YoY_growth to for example 2?

Comment: Review the *Format Function* topic in Access' built-in help system.

Comment: Can't get this to work..
SELECT q1.Year, q1.TotalOrders, q1.TotalRevenue, IIF(q0.TotalRevenue Is Null ,Null, Format(((q1.TotalRevenue - q0.TotalRevenue) / q0.TotalRevenue),"Percent") AS YoY
FROM q4Data AS q1 LEFT JOIN q4Data AS q0 ON q1.Year = (q0.Year + 1);

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the edit to your earlier comment ... so I thought you had shown us your working solution.  Looks like there was a missing `)` after `"Percent")`  If it's still not working right, please open a new question and give us the full text of any error message.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is something like this?

```
Year    Revenue     Growth
2014    55
2015    246         4.47
2016    350         1.42
```

You could wrap the original query a twice to get the number from both years.

```
select orders.year, orders.orders, orders.revenue, 
    (select (orders.revenue/subOrders.revenue)
        from 
        (
        --originalQuery or table link
        ) subOrders
        where subOrders.year = (orders.year-1)
    ) as lastYear
from
(
--originalQuery or table link
) orders
```

here's a cheap union'd table example.

```
select orders.year, orders.orders, orders.revenue, 
    (select (orders.revenue/subOrders.revenue)
        from 
        (
        select 2014 as year, 2 as orders, 55.20 as revenue
        union select 2015 as year, 2 as orders, 246.28 as revenue
        union select 2016 as year, 7 as orders, 350.47 as revenue
        ) subOrders
        where subOrders.year = (orders.year-1)
    ) as lastYear
from
(
select 2014 as year, 2 as orders, 55.20 as revenue
union select 2015 as year, 2 as orders, 246.28 as revenue
union select 2016 as year, 7 as orders, 350.47 as revenue
) orders
```

Comment: I think you are missing a `FROM/JOIN orders` in somewhere

Comment: When I ran it in MSSQL studio, it worked. It might be cleaner to have both of the OriginalQuery calls in the main "from" section, but this localizes it. Not my prettiest work.

Comment: I think is a good effort. But dont know how `orders.year` will work I dont see `orders` anywhere beside field declaration, and only see one `subOrders` alias.